# "These" or "those" (or perhaps neither of them)?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

From an English Reading test:

> '[...] Think of an interview as a highly focused professional conversation. You should spend the limited amount of time you have learning about *the employer's needs* and discuss the ways you can meet ____ needs. In many cases, you will be interviewed at least twice before being...'

Which one should I choose to fill in the gap, "these" or "those"?

Comment: That should probably be *the limited*, not *your limited*, and it should definitely be *at least twice*, not just *least twice*.  The practice test you’re taking might not be very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine. We could understand ***these*** as meaning *the needs I'm talking about **right now***, and ***those*** as meaning *the needs that I **just mentioned***, but in practice the choice doesn't affect the "meaning" in any way in OP's exact cited context.

As a general principle, ***these*** usually refers to things which are "nearer" than ***those*** - where "nearer" could mean *physically closer, more relevant to the current context, more recently mentioned,* etc.

In contexts where the referent(s) are physically present - particularly if *both* plural pronouns (or their singular equivalents ***this*** and ***that***) are used within a single utterance - people often use hand gestures to clarify the referent(s)...

> Customer: *Good morning. I'd like to buy some widgets*.
>    Shopkeeper: *No problem! Do you want **these**<sup>1</sup> or **those**<sup>2</sup>?*
>
> [pointing while speaking, to *these widgets<sup>1</sup> **right here*** or *those other widgets<sup>2</sup> **over there***]

As an alternative that would more explicitly emphasise the actual point being made, OP might consider ***their*** needs (since the context is specifically about the ***employer's*** needs, not the prospective ***employee's*** needs).

Answer (score -1):

I you the things are close to the speaker you should use “these,” and if they are away you should use “those".

Comment: That's a good (although not foolproof) generalization. However, the question is talking about _employer's needs_. Would you say that something abstract like "needs" are close to the speaker, or far away from the speaker?